У меня есть txt файл который нужно очистить в пайтон
Код записывает данные в файл result.txt и при каждом запуске мне нужно его очищать
пример до 2-го запуска кода:
1
2
3

при 2-ом запуске файл может стать к примеру
3
2
1

и в файле не должно оставаться 1 2 3 при 2 запуске

А в чем вопрос то?

Если при каждом запуске файл нужно очищать, потом что-то в него записывать - просто открывайте файл в режиме записи ("w")

для связки: Как перезаписать файл в python

Попробуй следующее:
# указываем путь и имя файла с расширением
filePathName = 'D:/result.txt'
# открываем файл с параметром 'w' - это означает, что файл будет отчищаться
# перед тем как записать новые данные и после записи сам закроется с сохранением
# данных
with open(filePathName, 'w') as file:
    file.write("Новые данные") # записываем новые данные


Почитайте о PEP8 (filePathName -> file_path_name)

@wchistow Формально pathname - это одно слово...

@Akina, пожалуй... а вообще-то лучше всего наверное будет просто filepath.

Ммм... вряд ли. filepath - это скорее путь к файлу, только без имени самого файла. Кажется, что хватило бы просто path, но это не так - с учётом существования файловых потоков ( для потока x:\folder\name.ext:stream формально path=\folder\ , тогда как filepath=\folder\name.ext: ). Хотя это, конечно, экзотика и вообще фенечки.

with open('result.txt', 'w') as f: pass

Я не уверен, что понял вопрос, т.к. не некорректно сформулирован, но возможно, данный код поможет. Он откроет файл в режиме записи (w), что, по идее, приведёт к удалению  содержимого и обнулению размера. Вроде так.
